# How to show/hide a div based on radio button class?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code of HTML inside a form

```
<input class="show-uploader" type="radio" name="mal" value="myval">
```

When user click on this value i want to show a div with a class: .mydiv

```
 $("input[name=mal]").change(function() {
    $(".mydiv").show();
});
```

Can i do somthing like:

```
$(".show-uploader").click(function () {
    $(".mydiv").toggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Dossent relly work, no div is shown after click on my radiobutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
$(".show-uploader").click(function () {
    $(".mydiv").toggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/yemhv302/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("input[name=mal]").change(function() {
    $(".mydiv").show();
});
```

Since you are using radios regardless which radio you check in the group is is always going to show the div. There is no reason why it shouldn't show with the above code. Are you sure it has the class of mydiv?

Here is a fiddle with your code. I assumed you have the css that is in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3a7g4gcp/

Here is a fiddle with modified code for a show/hide radio where i'm checking to see if the .show-uploader class item is checked and showing div or hiding div depending.

http://jsfiddle.net/to2sz4m2/

```
$("input[name=mal]").change(function() {
    $('.show-uploader').is(':checked') ? $('.mydiv').show() :  $('.mydiv').hide() ;   
});
```